# Facebook API - Unsupported get request for Test Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This problem seems to coincide with facebook's API version change.

When I call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{album-id}/photos?access_token={access_token}
```

I expect it to return the photos in the specific album. This works when I use my own facebook account or a friends. However when I try to use a test user set up in facebook I'm now getting

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I've tried specifying the version number

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/...
```

Can someone explain why this call no longer works for test users and still works for 'real' users? I can make the previous '/me/albums' call without any errors on both real and test accounts.

These are the permissions for the test user...

```
{
 "data": 
 [{
     "permission": "user_birthday",
     "status": "granted"
  },
  {
     "permission": "user_photos",
     "status": "granted"
  },
  {
     "permission": "email",
     "status": "granted"
  },
  {
     "permission": "public_profile",
     "status": "granted"
  }
 ]}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The album privacy setting and photos privacy settings might be relevant. You should be able to get them if both are set to PUBLIC. Otherwise, it looks like a bug, I would suggest you to [report it here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).

Comment: I have the same problem when requesting mutual friends on a test user. Seems like a very misleading and unhelpful error response.